# Image data agumentation tequniques using keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

I would like to generate augmented data for images by Random rotation, shifts, shear and flips.

I have found [this](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) `keras` function.

The function `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` But I've seen this being used to directly train networks.

Is there a way to input images and then save the transformed images on HDD instead of how if currently works in examples in this [link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/)

Or is there another simple plug and use python package I can use instead of implementing everything with `numpy` or `opencv` ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically - this is `generator` which is infinitely returning a batches of images. One could do the following:

```
def save_images_from_generator(maximal_nb_of_images, generator):
    nb_of_images_processed = 0
    for x, _ in generator:
        nb_of_images += x.shape[0]
        if nb_of_images <= maximal_nb_of_images:
            for image_nb in range(x.shape[0]):
                your_custom_save(x[image_nb]) # your custom function for saving images
        else:
            break
```

to save images from `keras` image generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the images outputted by ImageGenerator to HDD. One option is to use datagen.flow as follows:

```
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9, save_to_dir='images', save_prefix='aug', save_format='png')
```

A second option is to manually loop over each image, load it, and apply a random transformation. Once you have instantiated your ImageGenerator, just call:

```
img_trans = datagen.random_transform(img)
```

Then, save the transformed image to HDD using PIL etc.

A third option is to manually loop over each image, load it, and apply a random transformation using a third party program. I recommend imgaug, found [here](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug).